# How to choose k in Shi-Malik Algorithm?

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis

I'm wondering how one chooses a specific k in [Shi-Malik Algo.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96539/motivations-for-shi-malik-algorithm) 
Do we choose several ks and rank them via their SSE measures?
Does k reflect the number of clusters we assume for the data?

kind regards Mikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, K is the number of natural grouping we believe their is in the data.

You can find K by exploring the eigenvalues.
One tool which is particularly designed for spectral clustering is the **Eigengap heuristic** (also called spectral gap) - number of clusters k is usually given by the value of k that maximizes the eigengap (difference between consecutive eigenvalues).  i.e., choose the number k such that all eigenvalues λ1, . . . , λk are very small, but λk+1 is relatively large. 
The larger this eigengap is, the closer the eigenvectors of the ideal case and hence the better spectral clustering works. If you're interested on the justifications for this procedure, it is based on perturbation theory and spectral graph theory. 
You can read more here: [A Tutorial on Spectral Clustering - Ulrike von Luxburg](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5B0%5D.pdf)

Other way to explore the natural grouping: number of **connected components and the spectrum of the Laplacian matrix** - the number of times 0 appears as an eigenvalue in the Laplacian is the number of connected components in the graph. Your affinity matrix can be considered as a graph and then, try to look how many connected components you have in the graph. That will give you a sense of the neutral structure of your data..

In addition, as you mentioned, we can set a validation criterion (for example, **SSE**) and see its value under different values of K. That's fine once you have a **labeled** data (which is not always the case in clustering) and you know that this criterion/quality measure is really meaningful.